# NullReference at ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net

1 Solution.

2 Projects (1.WEB - 2. Three Layered Structure)

Calling a stored procedure:
Web -> BOL -> BLL -> DAL.

**DAL's Method**: gets the connection string and the executes.

```
 public DataSet ExecuteSQL(string sp, Persona user)
    {
        EH eh = new EH(); // Error_Handling.cs object
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string connectionString = null;
            connectionString = GetNewConnection("BO"); //HERE COMES THE ERROR
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            using (conn)
            { ....
```

**GetNewConnection().**

```
 public string GetNewConnection(string server)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

**App.Config** fragment naming the desired connection

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="BO"
    connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=BO;User ID=WebUser;Password=333;Integrated Security=False"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I get the following Exception when returning from GetNewConnection()

- $exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

Why is it getting a null reference?

Comment: **App.config** for a **web** project? Shouldn't that be **web.config**?

Comment: BTW: at `GetNewConnection`, shouldn't you use the `server` argument instead of hard coding `"BO"`?

Comment: @AndreCalil Yes, this is for testing purposes.

Comment: DLLs do not usually have their own configuration files (the configuration system certainly doesn't have defaults that make that kind of scenario easy). This is because DLLs are loaded into an executable process - the configuration system assumes all configuration will be part of that executable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the **ConnectionString** in the Web.Config of the UI project, Your **WEB** Project

Copy that `ConnectionString` section and Paste in your **Web.Config** and it should work fine

Comment: But I want it to be in DLL. Because once the system is running. WebPage will probably be on another location. So, if Web requests go to one server for C#, and then before executing SQL it has to go to another server to get the connectionstring, and then go back again to the other server to excute SQL... It sounds like a waste of time. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes - the DLL will be on the web server as part of the web project

Comment: You will be deploying your web files & the DLL's(data access layer project DLL ) together in the same server, rite ? same bin folder of the web app ?

Comment: @Shyju oh, I got confussed, yes, they'll be together in the same server.

Answer (score 3):

The connectionstring should be in the `web.config`, not the `app.config`

Comment: Check comment on previuos answer please.